# C# Application.ExecutablePath on WPF Framework 3.5

Tags: c#, wpf, path, executable

This line is fine in a WinForm Framework3.5 but not in a WPF Framework3.5.

```
Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

How can I get the exe path on a WPF app ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are several ways to get exe path. Try the next:

- Application.StartupPath
- Path.GetDirectoryName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[0])
- Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName)
- Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location)
- System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location

Comment: `Assembly.Location` can return `null` in some cases, it is better to use `AssemblyName.CodeBase`, the example is below by Ned Stoyanov

Comment: Process is IDisposable, which means that you have to wrap the third option with a `using` block

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( 
  System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase );
```

Comment: `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( new Uri(
  System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase).LocalPath );` - this is correct, `CodeBase` returns URL, and `Path.GetDirectoryName(...)` doesn't work with URLs

Answer (score 1):

You can unpack a Uri like this:

```
string codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase;
   UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
   string path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uri.Path);
```