# Cannot get App.exe from a separate White project

Tags: c#, wpf, white-framework

I'm trying to get some automated UI tests set up for a WPF application I'm working on in order to exercise the UI but I can't seem to get the app to run even using an explicit path. Because these tests need to run on any machine including our build server, it needs to be a relative path so it can run anywhere. I've looked at a few different questions, [C# Application.ExecutablePath on WPF Framework 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17966871/c-sharp-application-executablepath-on-wpf-framework-3-5) and [Getting the application's directory from a WPF application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938421/getting-the-applications-directory-from-a-wpf-application) for examle, and neither of those worked.

Here's an example of what my project structure looks like

```
Solution
 AccepatanceTestProject
  UITest.cs
 MainApp
  MainApp
  Bin
   Debug
    MainApp.Exe
```

I'm trying to access the MainApp.exe in MainApp\Bin\Debug\MainApp.exe from AcceptanceTestProject\UITest.cs

System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location seems to be the most suggested option, but this returns the path to the UITest.cs executable directory. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have you referred to the [Samples](https://github.com/TestStack/White/tree/master/src/Samples)?

Comment: @JoshuaShearer Yep, following their example of using  Path.GetDirectoryName(new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).AbsolutePath);

Returns:
"C:\\source\\repo\\project\\UI.Tests\\bin\\Debug"

Answer (score 0):

In case your MainApp.exe and your test are always in the same solution, you can use the path below to access the MainApp.exe.

```
string path = @"..\..\..\MainApp\Bin\Debug\MainApp.exe";
```